# Difficulties using Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

So basically I have the following lines of code in Jupyter (after the imports):

```
def get_SpeciesTypes_choices():
    df = pd.read_csv(path.join("...static\\Data\\AnimalCross.csv"))
    df = df.groupby('Species').sum()
    l = df.index
    m = list(zip(l , l))
    return m
form = get_SpeciesTypes_choices()
```

Then I have the data and after that I have:

```
form.SpeciesTypes.choices = get_SpeciesTypes_choices()
df = df.loc[form.SpeciesTypes.data]
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-170542ef779d> in <module>
----> 1 form.SpeciesTypes.choices = get_SpeciesTypes_choices()
      2 df = df.loc[form.SpeciesTypes.data]

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'SpeciesTypes'
```

Comment: You say you are having trouble in Jupyter. Does this code work in other environments?

Comment: Your function returns a list. But you are trying to use form.SpeciesTypes as a data frame. So list will not look for attributes or columns like data frame.

Comment: Yeah, it's meant to throw that error because form here is a list. You can't do things like `form.SpeciesTypes.choices`

Comment: @snatchysquid It works in visual studios but I need to move it to Jupyter to progress.

Answer (score 0):

Form is a list list do not have `SpeciesTypes`, not a dataframe column. Try adding it as one